# can't able to select top level maven targets at pre step in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am a Jenkins newbie and am trying to add pre build step-- Invoke top level manven targets in job.

I can see this option in pre build steps but i cant able to select it but remaing all options  i can access.

when i select "execte shell" i can see some options like commands area which are related to excute shell, but with "top level maven targets" i cant see any thing.

How would I get the above mentioned step in Jenkins?  Any help will be much appreciated.

thanq

Comment: Where exactly is pre-build step? Do you mean Build step?

Comment: It's a build step of a Maven-style project that is executed before the main Maven build step.

Answer (score 0):

You should see this (after clicking the <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> button). If you don't see this, there is a conflict between the plugin and your Jenkins version.

- First, try re-installing the plugin, maybe get the latest version.
- Try updating the Jenkins version number too.

[image]